# cannot set property of multidimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

My JavaScript code is this:

```
var i=0;
var ret=[];
ret[i][0]=newID;
ret[i][1]=jobTitle;
ret[i][2]=jobText;
ret[i][3]=jobEmail;
ret[i][4]=jobOrder;
```

These are all strings and all have value.
I'm getting the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined" on the 
>   first assignment: ret[i][0]=newID;

Also error at jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Zf9rE/2/

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must create `ret[i]` before you try to add elements to it:

```
var i=0;
var ret=[];

ret[i] = []; // define ret[i]

ret[i][0]=newID;
ret[i][1]=jobTitle;
ret[i][2]=jobText;
ret[i][3]=jobEmail;
ret[i][4]=jobOrder;
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf9rE/5/)

Unless there is a reason to hard code the array indexes, you might prefer to either create an array literal (as @Rocket shows in the comments) or use [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
ret[i].push(newID);
ret[i].push(jobTitle);
```

Comment: Or even better: `ret[i] = [newID,jobTitle,jobText,jobEmail,jobOrder];` ;-)

Comment: `var ret = [ [newID,jobTitle,jobText,jobEmail,jobOrder] ];` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach:

```
var jobTitle="j title";
var jobText = "j desc";
var jobEmail="jemail";
var jobOrder="j order";
var newID="3";

var i=0;
var ret = new Array();
var matrix = new Array()

ret[0]=newID;
ret[1]=jobTitle;
ret[2]=jobText;
ret[3]=jobEmail;
ret[4]=jobOrder;

matrix[i] = ret;
console.log(matrix[0][0]);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/Zf9rE/6/